# Home network switch and cable category

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, power-supply, switch

I have few questions about home network. The architecture is as follows:

- fiber cable to home door
- from home door in box into the wall, separate cables are going to each room

The questions are:

- the box in the wall (where the IPS cable and room cables are going to be connected) is pretty small with no access to air (as it is closed); as there will be a switch, are there any heat concerns?
- as the room cables will be laid on the floor, which is later concreted what types of cable to use:

  [image]

  High class Cat6 cable seems OK, as it is standardize, uses RJ45. As I have read, Cat7 is not
  [recommended](https://www.cablematters.com/blog/Networking/what-is-cat7-and-why-you-don-t-need-it). The question is there any purpose for home network (in the future years) to support 40 Gbps (Cat8)?
- I guess that there is no point of switch like [this](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/surveillance-switch/tl-sg1016pe/v2/) as it support to 1Gbps, and need to get someone like [this](https://www.netgear.com/business/wired/switches/fully-managed/m4300-16x-600w-psu.html#techspecs%E2%80%8B) even currently the IPS is not delivering such speed; I am worrying about heat issues and noise as both seems to big (at least bigger and more complex than my current 6 ports one). Should I be worried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fair of opinion to this question, but I would offer two specific points:

1. I have not seen much consumer / general commercial switch gear that that can permanently survive zero ventilation. Remember you will need to service this gear. You can keep it is a ventilated cabinet if visible in a residence.
2. While CAT 6e spec is good into the future for any home, make sure is it is enclosed in conduit in the concrete which is certified for burial in concrete.

Using properly installed conduit allows you to change cable category if you need it. I have been 25 years on CAT5 e / CAT 6 e with no degradation.

> switch ....I am worrying about heat issues and noise as both seems to
> big (at least bigger and more complex than my current 6 ports one).
> Should I be worried?

Any switch, router, modem and like needs to be ventilated. Yes, you need to be concerned about heat.

Comment: So, it will be better the switch not to be in a box in the wall I guess. Maybe on shelf on the wall then.

Comment: Yes. In a residence you can make a nice cabinet with bottom and side vents for ventilation to hold switch gear. This stuff (modem, router switches) will not last as long a cable in conduit.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve built houses, I’ve done installs, and I’ve been in InfoSec for decades.

It is a bad idea to pour concrete over cables. I assume this is what you mean by “concreted.” What you need to do is place runs of conduit (pipes) that are designed to be placed in concrete and run your cables through the conduit. This does several things.

1. Makes it so that if a cable is damaged, it can be pulled and run again.
2. When it is time to upgrade the cable, you can pull it and run new cable.
3. You don’t run the risk of damaging Ethernet with concrete.

You want to know what category of Ethernet cable to place? The answer is in the switch you’ll be using. Does it have RJ-45 ports? If yes, then Cat6 or Cat8 is your answer.

You then ask if you need to worry about Cat8. I don’t think anyone can tell you when 40Gbps will be a requirement between devices in the home. How quickly will VR develop? How many Internet connected devices will you own? Are you going to set up your own security system that’s IP based? You are the only person that can determine this.

Do keep in mind that Thunderbolt 3 has a theoretical maximum speed of 40 Gbps. This allows transfer of data from a host to storage/video.

Comment: Yes, they are are going to be placed in pipes - I should be more specific. Do you have a comment about the switch box? If it needs to be on air maybe it is better to design not to be in a box in the wall?